# Return promise from Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service that (when it's all said and done) updates a value on the database.

I would like to update the view scope based on the result (success/fail) but of course the http request used by the service is asynchronous so the return value is not immediately available and comes up undefined in the controller.

If I were making the http request inside the controller, I would update the scope inside the callback function, but because Im using a service, the scope's umm... scope(?) is not available to it.

Im thinking a Promise is what I need to be returning but perhaps there is something more simple.

**SERVICE**

```
.service('doStuff',function($http){

    this.update = function(data) {

        $http.post('http://api.internet', data).then(function(res){ 

            return(res.data.result);

        });  

    }

})
```

**CONTROLLLER**

```
/* service is injected into controller etc. */

var result = doStuff.update(data);

p(result); // undefined (as expected)
```

I figured since Im returning from the http callback, it would wait for the result to be available before returning but I guess Im missing something.

Comment: Your method `this.update` doesn't actually return anything. You need to change it to `return $http.post(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foremost, you need to return the query itself. Looks like

```
this.update = function(data) {

    return $http.post('http://api.internet', data).then(function(res){ 

        return(res.data.result);

    });  

}
```

Next step, you need get out of the promise function.

```
doStuff.update(data)
  .then(function(res) {
    //someone if request is success
  })
  .catch(function(rej) {
    //someone if request is reject
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `$http` is always async, you cannot return anything in the call back function. It is as good as not returning anything.

What you need to do is you need to return the `$http` promise, and then handle the callback functions in your controller.

Service:

```
.service('doStuff', function($http) {
  this.update = function(data) {
    return $http.post('http://api.internet', data);
  }
})
```

Controller:

```
doStuff.update(data).then(function(result){
  p(result);
});
```

Comment: so, in effect, OP just needs to add `return` before `$http.post`